# Iframe style code behind C#

Tags: c#, html, code-behind

I am trying to set each button to control the style of an iframe in c#. 
The HTML code is as follows

```
style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -185px; height: 100%; margin-top: -533px; width: 100%;">
```

I have my C# code as

```
IFrame.Attributes.Add("style", "height: 100%, Margin-top:-533px, margin-left: -185px, width: 100%,");
```

The issue is that the C# is not acting out like the HTML, How do I amend the C# code to behave like the HTML ? Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Why d'ont you do like this below :

```
IFrame.Attributes["style"] = "border: 0px none; margin-left: -185px; height: 100%; margin-top: -533px; width: 100%;";
```